# Setting a width to an item in a row prevents justifying the second item in the same row using TailwindCSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I have three items in two rows like:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-12">
  <div class="col-span-12 border-b-4 border-black">Item1</div>
  <div class="col-span-2 border-r-4 border-black">Item2</div>
  <div class="col-span-10">Item3</div>
</div>
```

I need to reduce the default width of Item2 using w-14 and I need to justify Item3 to the left. I am using tailwind CSS v3.3.3.

After adding w-14 to Item2 I tried various justifying options like justify-stretch, justify-items-stretch, justify-items-start, justify-self-auto, etc. to Item3, but none of those options helped justifying Item3 to the left (immediately adjacent to Item2). Item3 seem to stay put in its position.

Here is what I tried:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-12 justify-items-stretch">
  <div class="col-span-12 border-b-4 border-black">Item1</div>
  <div class="col-span-2 border-r-4 border-black w-14  justify-self-start">Item2</div>
  <div class="col-span-10">Item3</div>
</div>
```

which reduces the width of Item2 but does not left justify Item3.

Any hints on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`w-6/12` applies `width: 50%` and this `50%` would be `50%` of its column span,  `2`. The element would still occupy two columns but would only take up the width of one, hence it this one-column gap makes it look like the third item is not up against the second item.

To work around this, consider changing the second item to only occupy one grid column instead without the `width` and `justify-self` property values, thus giving the same visual effect. However, the second item will only occupy one grid column track, thus allowing the third item to be visually closer.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-12 justify-items-stretch">
  <div class="col-span-12 border-b-4 border-black">Item1</div>
  <div class="col-span-1 border-r-4 border-black">Item2</div>
  <div class="col-span-10">Item3</div>
</div>
```

---

## Question edit additional solution

Consider adjusting the column widths of the grid layout so that the second item's column size is what you'd want. This will mean that the third grid track where the third element starts from, will be at the end of the second item. This will mean the third element starts after the second item:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-[repeat(2,calc(theme(spacing.14)/2))_repeat(10,1fr)] justify-items-stretch">
  <div class="col-span-12 border-b-4 border-black">Item1</div>
  <div class="col-span-2 border-r-4 border-black">Item2</div>
  <div class="col-span-10">Item3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Wongjn, I have edited my post to update w-6/12 to w-14. Your code does not reduce the width of Item2. After applying w-14 to Item2 to reduce the width, I need to left justify Item3.

Comment: I have added a solution to your changed question.